# Rotating matrices to display data from radar onto a HUD

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, rotations, triangulation

I'm trying to write a code (in-game scripts) that takes data from radar (distance, azimuth, elevation) and displays points on a HUD in front of the player. Yesterday, I've managed to visualize radar data on a top-down display (i.e. projecting target locations on a 2D map). Today, I'm trying to draw a point on a HUD that is in front of the player, so it will overlay the actual object in-game (how HUDs kinda usually works).

To my disposal are:

- data from radar (distance $d$, azimuth $\alpha$, elevation $\epsilon$) of the target in radians
- $(X,Y)$ coordinates of my vehicle
- roll $\phi$, pitch $\theta$, yaw $\psi$ (in radians) of my vehicle

So far, I am super close to having it working. But the closer I am to the target, the higher (Y axis on HUD) the point goes, and I can't figure out why. This is what I'm using currently (and sorry for half-mathematical half-programmer syntax, my math background is barely high school):

- get original "local" unrotated radar data $l\alpha = sin(\alpha)$ for azimuth and $l_\epsilon = cos(\epsilon)$ for elevation
- rotate both azimuth and elevation along Y axis (using matrix rotation, however the in-game engine does not support matrix operations so I had to dissect it) around roll and pitch to get my "new" $(X,Y)$ coordinates
  $$
  target_x = ((l_\alpha * cos \phi) + (l_\epsilon * sin \phi)) * d\\
  target_y = (-(l_\alpha * sin \theta) + (l_\epsilon * cos \theta)) * d
  $$
- draw the points on the screen, for $X = (screenWidth / 2) - (target_x / 2)$ and for $Y = target_y / 2$

As my understanding of all of this goes, I basically need to get the radar's elevation to become my display's Y axis, and my radar's azimuth angle to become X axis on the screen. And we do that by taking those measurements and rotating it "around" my vehicle's roll and pitch values (since they are my "new" $X,Y$ axes).

I'm not 100% certain if I'm even doing this correctly, for example I'm multiplying both axes with $d$ but that shouldn't be the case (maybe if I want to scale the points based on distance but I don't need that). Because in this version, the closer I get to the target, the greater the error is. If anyone would be interested, here is the relevant part of the code in Lua: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XUtK84br)

Am I missing something super basic (granted, I've learned about matrices literally yesterday), or some concept is totally unbeknown to me.. I've read that something like vector plane intersection might be a solution for this, but as I've mentioned, math is extremely not my thing and I had no idea what I was looking at while checking out that. Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Is the data from the radar with respect to your vehicle?  Is your HUD fixed with respect to your vehicle?  If you think of your HUD as a 2D display, what are the axis orientations of the vertial and horizonal axis?  A raster might have x to the right and y down.

Comment: @Tpofofn Yes, it is with respect to my vehicle. But I am also able to calculate absolute position in the world (relative to world centre, via GPS module). The HUD is indeed fixed too. All displays and other euclidean coordinate systems in the game have 0,0 (or 0,0,0 for that matter) in the topmost left corner, with X going right, Y going down and Z going away from "me".

Comment: Then the location and orientation of your vehicle are irrelevant.  You just need the azimuth and elevation (and perhaps distance) to map the radar location to an (x,y) location on your HUD.  To do the transformation, you should read up on homogeneous coordinates.  https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/explaining-homogenous-coordinates-and-projective-geometry/

Comment: @Tpofofn Wow, that looks like a very useful thing. Too bad that the game's Math library lacks functions that works with matrices, but I can figure it out. Anyways, this: - the point where the line and the plane intersect is (x/z, y/z, 1) - is probably what I was looking for the entire time. Thanks a lot, will definately read more about this

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you need.